# Ember data discards irregular attributes

Tags: ember.js

I have a model attribute with JSON key 'custom-device-label-1' that I would expect to find as 'customDeviceLabel1' but instead it is just not there and the model attribute is undefined even though the payload had data.

Comment: I would suggest showing your work. What adapter are you using? What serializer are you using? How are your models defined? What does the payload look like? How is something just _not there_? etc.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 possibilities: Either remove the dash between **label** and **1** at server-payload serialization...

```
custom-device-label1 //not custom-device-label-1
```

... or customize your serializer:

If you cannot manipulate the payload of your server, you could customize your model's serializer: 
[customize serializers](https://guides.emberjs.com/v3.0.0/models/customizing-serializers/)

In your case I would recommend following serializer-customization:

```
// app/serializers/your-model.js (ember g serializer your-model)
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.JSONAPISerializer.extend({

  keyForAttribute: function(attr) {
    if(attr === 'customDeviceLabel1') {
      return 'custom-device-label-1';
    }
    else {
      return this._super(...arguments);
    }
  }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding slightly on the answer wuarmin provided.

By default, Ember will take the property name in the model and dasherizes it.
This means de-camelizing the property name and replacing any spaces or underscores with a dash.

The character boundary in de-camelize accepts a numeric value in the lowercase section beforehand.

```
str.replace(/([a-z\d])([A-Z])/g, '$1_$2').toLowerCase())
```

If you're needing to override these rules,  extend the [keyForAttribute](https://emberjs.com/api/ember-data/2.15/classes/DS.JSONSerializer/methods/keyForAttribute?anchor=keyForAttribute) method in either your serializer.  Alternately, change the key in your json response.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, got caught up in work, when it needs to get done sometimes you just have to put nose to grindstone and find an answer on you own. Which in this case was a serializer with attrs block.

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
import Ember from 'ember';

export default DS.JSONAPISerializer.extend({
attrs: {
    customDeviceLabel1: 'custom-device-label-1',
    customDeviceLabel2: 'custom-device-label-2',
    customDeviceLabel3: 'custom-device-label-3',
    customDeviceLabel4: 'custom-device-label-4',
    customDeviceLabel5: 'custom-device-label-5',
    customDeviceLabel6: 'custom-device-label-6'
  }
});
```

also if I had chosen the right camel case e.g. 'customDeviceLabel_1' it would have just worked.